# VS 2022 publishing docker image to hub.docker.com

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2022, dockerhub

Looks like publishing in VS 2022 to hub.docker.com (free account) does not work correctly.

I have registered a free account on hub.docker.com. I did not create any projects.

I made a sample WebApi project and went on to publish it to Docker Hub Container Registry. When you choose Docker Hub as DCR, VS2022 provides 3 options:

- Publish to personal repository (checkbox)
- username
- password (optional)

So, I left 1 options checked (wanted it as personal), I entered docker hub username (not email) and password.

When I clicked on publish, image was published to docker hub into the public repository (not private), with the name: myusername/myprojectname:latest

I can live with the bug with not publishing to private repository, but I would like to change the name of the image. So this is what I did:

- I deleted repository from docker hub to start over.
- I edited publish options in VS to change the tag from latest to automatically generated - that works OK (now its published as myusername/myprojectname:20220806160216).
- I edited project settings and added line with DockerfileBuildArguments:

  ```
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
    <DockerfileBuildArguments>-t myusername/customname</DockerfileBuildArguments>
  ```

However, it did not made any difference, image was still published as myusername/myprojectname. I tried with

```
  <DockerfileBuildArguments>-t customname</DockerfileBuildArguments>
```

and also did not make any difference, image still published with project name.

Anyone knows if this is a known bug with VS, or I am doing something wrong?

**Edit:**

I just looked at the build output, and I can see that VS passes two -t parameters, which obviously should not happen:

```
docker build -f "...SolutionDir\myProjectName\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t myprojectname -t myusername/customname --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=MyProjectName" "...SolutionDir"
```

Comment: all images in dockerhub need to be in a namespace, i.e. your username. You cannot push an image without namespace, doesn't matter if it's private. Personal is also not interchangebale with private. It means its not your organizations account, for example.

Comment: @TheFool I get that, and that can be seen in docker build command (username/projectname). Still, it does not allow to change image name, looks like its a bug, I have contacted MS. I am not sure what does this have to do with organization, as I said this is a new account, personal, free, and allows one repository to be private. Two problems are: 1) VS does not create the repository as private, although set to do so, and 2) VS does not allow you to change image name.

Comment: As per your description, you checked *personal* not *private*. Semantically this is a difference.

Comment: @TheFool In VS it says personal. I am not sure what is the meaing behing this, I understood it means private repository.

Comment: @TheFool Yep, I just read the documentation, it is personal. If unckecked, then you must login to your organization account. So this means that it will by default publish to public repository, since there is not option to select public / private.

Comment: you could probably work around that by create the repo first and making it private.